# Pandas :Add certain row of a dataframe to a certain row of the other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Want to do this:

```
df1=
A B C Max
1 2 3 C
4 2 1 A
3 5 2 B
3 2 4 C
7 5 2 A

df2= 
A B C Max
1 1 2 C
2 1 1 A
1 2 1 B
```

return:

```
A B C Max
2 3 5 C
6 3 2 A
4 7 3 B
4 3 6 C
9 6 3 A
```

Basically, df1 add the row from df2 with the same max.
Is there any convenient way to do it?

Comment: Is df2 an actually dict or a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
mask = df2.iloc[0:2]
frames = [df2, mask]
result = pd.concat(frames)
result.index = range(len(result))
df3 = df1.add(result)
df3['Max'] = df1['Max']
df3
```

Output:

```
A B C Max
2 3 5 C
6 3 2 A
4 7 3 B
4 3 6 C
9 6 3 A
```

Above id the answer to your original question but depending on what you're trying to do, there are also other ways to approach this. For example if you want to know the `sum` of each unique value in `Max` you can also use `pivot_table`.
First you can concatenate `df1` and `df2`:

```
new = [df1,df2]
df4 = pd.concat(new)
df4.index = range(len(df4))
df4
A   B   C   Max
0   1   2   3   C
1   4   2   1   A
2   3   5   2   B
3   3   2   4   C
4   7   5   2   A
5   1   1   2   C
6   2   1   1   A
7   1   2   1   B
```

Then, you can use the `pivot_table` to get the `sum` of values `A`, `B` and `C`

```
pd.pivot_table(df4,index=['Max'], values=['A', 'B', 'C'], aggfunc = [np.sum])
```

Output:

```
sum
    A   B   C
Max             
A   13  8   4
B   4   7   3
C   5   5   9
```